# A specific type of painting style, named after a Frenchman

Tags: terminology

What is the term called, named after a Frenchman, that refers to profile paintings of human faces that are usually black and white and only show contours?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **silhouette**  n.
>
> 1. A drawing consisting of the outline of something, especially a human profile, filled in with a solid color.
> 2. An outline that appears dark against a light background. See Synonyms at outline.
>
> tr.v. silhouetted, silhouetting, silhouettes: To cause to be
>   seen as a silhouette; outline: *Figures were silhouetted against the
>   setting sun.*
>
> [French, after Étienne de Silhouette (1709-1767), French finance
>   minister.] [AHDEL]

Comment: I honestly did not know this was named after a person.  Well done, Edwin.

Comment: In all honesty, if I ever did, I'd forgotten. It seemed to fit, though.